# Scheduling threads within a process

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, scheduling

Say I have a process with 4 threads, and I want them to run according to specific scheduling algorithm. I searched and found `pthread_setschedparam` and `sched_setschedparam` functions for selecting an algorithm and setting priorities of a thread, but I saw one thing that was unclear - `pthread_setschedparam` takes a thread name and sets it's own scheduling policy. What does that mean specifically, since I thought all threads within a process are scheduled according to one policy, which is set for the entire process.
Does that mean then that if I use `sched_setschedparam` and set a policy (since it refers to a process via it's PID) it will ensure that threads within that process run according to selected scheduling policy?

Code I'm writing is for Linux, I was using boost but had to resort to pthreads for this part.

Comment: The kernel scheduler is managing *all* the tasks (i.e. processes or threads) running on the system. You can't absolutely be sure that other tasks won't be scheduled (and they need to be running sometimes). You could investigate so called real-time process scheduling.

Answer (score 4):

`pthread_setschedparam` sets the scheduling parameters for a single thread. `sched_setscheduler` sets the scheduling parameters for an entire process. Different threads can indeed have different scheduling policies.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, so all I need to do is set each thread's policy individually by calling `pthread_setschedparam`

Comment: @Aerol: Or you could only set the *first* threads policy and set the "inherit" flag, which makes all threads spawned from that one have the same policy. I don't know how the "sched_" and the "thread_" function interact, but you could always make a small test case and try (use the `thread_getschedparam` function to query the current state).

Comment: I did just that, I have set the policy for the thread that creates all the other threads and they inherit it afterwards. They inherit policy from the main thread the same regardles of whether I set it with `pthread_setschedparam` or `sched_setscheduler`. Also I tried (to see effects of calling "sched_" on threads) to change policy and priority of the process with `sched_setscheduler` while the threads were already running and checked their policy after it with `pthread_getschedparam`, they are not affected by it